# Windows GRUB entry keeps disappearing

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

I have a system with dual boot:

1. Windows 10
2. Ubuntu 20.04

Every now and then the Windows entry disappears.
Then I run `sudo os-prober && sudo update-grub && reboot` and it's there after restart.

I can't understand why does it keep disappearing.
I've added `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to `/etc/default/grub` but no success.

Any idea what else should I configure?

Comment: As far as I know, os-prober itself doesn't write GRUB entry, it just tells the existence of OS. GRUB calls it and create entry according to it. How you can run update-grub without root privilage? Also, have you uncommented the modified line of `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan yes, I uncommented that line. As for sudo - I was calling the commands separetly with sudo, and just unified them wrongly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Forget os-prober, add static grub entry `/etc/grub/40_custom` .

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' -class windows {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root XXXX-XXX
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Replace XXXX-XXXX with UUID (not PARTUUID) found from `blkid /dev/sdXY` (or `/dev/nvmeXnYpZ`,  whichever applicable) for the EFI System partition, usually formated FAT. Applies to UEFI systems.